# jQuery ajax GET fails

Tags: post, jquery, get

I have the following jQuery ajax request in a .js file:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "Download.aspx/ZipCheck",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: "{}",
  dataType: "json",
  success: AjaxSucceeded,
  error: AjaxFailed
});

function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
  alert(result.d);
}

function AjaxFailed(result) {
  alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
}
```

The request fails and an alert pops up that says "200 OK". However, if I change the ajax request type to "POST" then it works and I have an alert that pops up with the expected data being returned from Download.aspx/ZipCheck.

**Why does the GET fail, and why does the POST succeed?** My understanding must be flawed about the difference between the two, because I thought that a GET request still would return something from the server.

Comment: Also check out the IE GET caching problem if the answer from Nick does not resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WebMethods are by default restricted to POST](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx), you need to explicitly enable the GET request, for example using [`UseHttpGet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.usehttpget.aspx) on the [`ScriptAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298830.aspx), like this:

```
[WebMethod, ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
public thing ZipCheck() {
  //return object
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Is there any advantage to using GET over POST? I mean, why go through the effort of GET enabling your webmethods when you can just use a POST request and be done with it?

Comment: @Jagd -See the blog post, first link for security issues...I'd say use a POST and be done with it :)

Comment: Thanks for that blog link of Scott Guthries. I will definitely stick to using POST now. :)